# What's the value in marking static methods in a non-static class

Tags: static-methods

I had a recent code review that gave me some slightly surprising feedback. It was in an instantiable service class that had a number of fully encapsulated private methods. In other words, methods that didn't reference any higher level functions or variables. For a trivial example:

```
private decimal IncreaseByPercent(decimal original, int percentageIncrease)
{
    return original + ((original / 100) * percentageIncrease);
}
```

The feedback suggested that methods like this should be marked as static. It's not a suggestion I've come across before: indeed I've rarely used static methods outside of static classes. What would be the advantages of doing so?

Comment: Unfortunately this question was closed before I could finish writing my answer. In addition to the answers in the "duplicate", it looks like you are using C#. If so, there's a very good reason to mark a method as static if you can: performance. "*After you mark the methods as static, the compiler will emit non-virtual call sites to these members ... [which] can achieve a measurable performance gain for performance-sensitive code.*": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245046.aspx

Comment: @DavidArno: The performance benefits are almost inconsequential in most cases.  "Performance-sensitive code" is a special case.  The real reason you mark private methods as static is to *indicate that you won't be touching instance state.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey, performance-sensitive code *used* to be a special case. The mass of crap added to C# 7.1 and 7.2 around passing structs by reference sadly shows those days are gone. Games and mobile (both of which are performance sensitive) is a big thing for MS these days and drives a lot of the C# language development.

Comment: @DavidArno: I don't know anything about C# 7.x, but based on your description it seems that these new constructs are better to be avoided (at least in game development), not papered over with `static` calls.

Comment: In the future, specify your language, as "static" can have several meanings.

Comment: This question should be left open as the duplicate implies the incorrect answer, for C#, at least. The Visual Studio analyzer produces a warning if you write an instance method using no instance data.